# Raise Notice function in tuple_only mode

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have been doing some research for a few weeks and found some suggestions to use a Raise Notice function in postgres to clean up the scripts a little and I liked the idea.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION raisenoticefunction(in errorMessage text) 
RETURNS void 
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '%', errorMessage;
END;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

So Instead of having to do this through all of the scripts, (which due to our coding standards is quite often):

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Creating table customerOrders';
END $$;
```

I can just do this, which is so much cleaner and easier to read and type:

```
SELECT raisenoticefunction('Creating table customerOrders');
```

The problem is I want to put just this function in tuple_only mode. I don't want the column header or the discarded row footer to be output with the notice.

I cannot set the tuple_only mode at the command line or in the config file because I do not want to turn this off for all functions, as some may require this information. Does anyone know how I can set just a single function to tuple_only mode?

Comment: What `tuple_only` mode? Are you talking about `--tuples-only` in psql?

Answer (score 1):

Your mention of "tuple_only" makes me suspect you are talking about psql functionality, which is the command-line interface and completely separate from PostgreSQL itself.

If I am guessing right, this would do what you ask for:

```
test=# \set QUIET \t \\ SELECT raisenoticefunction('foo'); \t \set QUIET off

NOTICE:  foo
```

`\t` .. equivalent to `\pset tuples_only` - toggles on / off
`\set QUIET` .. suppresses feedback from psql
`\\` ..  marks the end of arguments and continues parsing SQL commands

[More details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html)